# Firestore collectionGroup query returns empty result in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database setup is

[image]

i want to find "playerName" field value in "UserBasicInfo" subcollections. here is mycode:

```
`
```

Firebase.Firestore.Query query = db.CollectionGroup("UserBasicInfo").WhereEqualTo("playerName", name).Limit(1);

```
var queryNameTask = query.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

while (!queryNameTask.IsCompleted)
await Task.Yield();

```
        var querySnapshot = queryNameTask.Result;

        foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.Documents)
        {
            DatabasePlayerStats databasePlayerStats = documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<DatabasePlayerStats>();
            searchingName = databasePlayerStats.playerName;
        }`
```

even if "name" exist in "playerName" field value query always return empty.

here is my index Exemptions:

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to fetch, do you wan to get the document that have the field  ```player_uCI4``` ? or what exactly do you want to get ?

Comment: yes i want to get document that have the "playerName" field value same as query searched name .and in this example this is "player_uCI4".

Comment: I think you need to do a promise with the querySnapshot, you can see this [doc](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/get+documents+where+field+name+%3D+%22%22+firebase) that could help you

Comment: thanks for your response but actually i am using async await in c# and here is my rest code for query:  while (!queryNameTask.IsCompleted)
                await Task.Yield();

            var querySnapshot = queryNameTask.Result;  i think this same functionality as promise

Comment: i tried another query same path but this condition is WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo. and surprisingly query result is not empty but it provide WhereGreaterThan condition but not provide equal condition. here is my new query code: ` Query query = db.CollectionGroup("UserBasicInfo").WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("playerName", name);

            var queryNameTask = query.GetSnapshotAsync();

            while (!queryNameTask.IsCompleted)
                await Task.Yield();

            var querySnapshot2 = queryNameTask.Result;

            ` Could problem be related to the equality query only?

Comment: that really shock me I don't fully understand why with the ```whereEqualTo``` condition do not work and with the ```WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo``` the query return something, but I am glad that you are able to receive something now, I would suggest to put is as an answer for now, btw I think you edit the question and now code of the query is gone

Comment: thanks for response as you recommend i put comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried another query same path but this condition is WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo. and surprisingly query result is not empty but it provide WhereGreaterThan condition but not provide equal condition. here is my new query code:

```
Query query = db.CollectionGroup("UserBasicInfo").WhereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("playerName", name); var queryNameTask = query.GetSnapshotAsync(); while (!queryNameTask.IsCompleted) await Task.Yield(); var querySnapshot2 = queryNameTask.Result;
```

Could problem be related to the equality query only?

Comment: The string value I sent as a parameter to the query was the text value of the textmeshpro component. Although this value presents itself as a string expression written to the textmeshpro component, it always contains an extra single quotation mark in the text value. This caused the firebase query to work incorrectly. but I couldn't notice it because the string value looks normal while debugging. Error popped up when navigating the string expression with for. as a result firebase query works properly.

Comment: really good comment I will upvote the answer as well, I hope I could help you in any way, btw I fixed a little the question so it looks better